# ImGui errors when trying to make a game menu

Tags: shaders, rendering, imgui

I want to make a simple game menu, but I ran into a problem where ImGui cannot stop rendering and apart from that it throws shader errors. I initialize ImGui in this way:

```
IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO();
    (void)io;
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableKeyboard;
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableGamepad;

    ImGui::StyleColorsDark();

    ImGui_ImplSDL3_InitForOpenGL(window, gl_context);
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init("#version 300 es");
    
    while(is_running)
    {
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplSDL3_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();

        ImVec2 mainWindowSize = ImVec2(SCREEN_WIDTH/4, SCREEN_HEIGHT/4);
        ImVec2 uiPos = ImVec2(SCREEN_WIDTH/4,SCREEN_HEIGHT/4);
        ImGui::SetNextWindowSize(mainWindowSize);
        ImGui::SetWindowPos(uiPos);
        ImGui::Begin("Break Out!");

        if (ImGui::Button("Start"))
        {
            show_ui = false;
        }
        ImGui::End();

        if(show_ui)
        {
            ImGui::Render();
            ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());
        }
    }
```

ImGui doesn't stop rendering on button press, plus there are these errors from gl callback:

```
ERROR 1280 in glCreateShader
GL CALLBACK:  type = 0x8251, severity = 0x826b, message = type: 0, local: 0, shared: 0, gpr: 12, inst: 19, bytes: 304, cached: 1389
GL CALLBACK:  type = 0x8251, severity = 0x826b, message = type: 1, local: 0, shared: 0, gpr: 13, inst: 20, bytes: 320, cached: 1101
GL CALLBACK: ** GL ERROR ** type = 0x824c, severity = 0x9146, message = GL_INVALID_ENUM in glGetIntegerv(pname=GL_POLYGON_MODE)
GL CALLBACK: ** GL ERROR ** type = 0x824c, severity = 0x9146, message = GL_INVALID_ENUM in glIsEnabled(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART)
GL CALLBACK: ** GL ERROR ** type = 0x824c, severity = 0x9146, message = GL_INVALID_ENUM in glDisable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART)
GL CALLBACK: ** GL ERROR ** type = 0x824c, severity = 0x9146, message = GL_INVALID_OPERATION in unsupported function called (unsupported extension or deprecated function?)
GL CALLBACK: ** GL ERROR ** type = 0x824c, severity = 0x9146, message = GL_INVALID_ENUM in glDisable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART)
GL CALLBACK: ** GL ERROR ** type = 0x824c, severity = 0x9146, message = GL_INVALID_OPERATION in unsupported function called (unsupported extension or deprecated function?)
```

those errors do not appear when not using ImGui